# Hello, can you tell me how to limit the length of the "plot" line

Tags: plot, pine-script

can you tell me how to limit the length of the "plot" line so that it ends at, say, the 5th bar after my condition has worked?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `barssince` function and check if it is less then 5.

In the example below there is a `simple moving average` and a `crossover` functions to create a trigger condition. Also to avoid a continious plot use `plot.style_linebr` argument :

```
sma20 = sma(close, 20)

someCondition = crossover(close, sma20)
plotLimit = barssince(someCondition) < 5

plot(plotLimit ? sma20 : na, "SMA", color.blue, 2, plot.style_linebr)
```